# Symbolication process on UNIX server refering Xcode.app

Tags: xcode, unix, symbolicate

I ran the symbolication process from the command line on the Mac-Terminal and it works fine. I am trying to push the same script on to the UNIX server which fails to run, since its trying to refer the Xcode.app which is not present on to the server. 
Getting the following error on server :

*xcode-select: Error: No Xcode is selected. Use xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app to select /Applications/Xcode.app, or see the xcode-select manpage (man xcode-select) for further information.*

Obvious answer could be that I move the Xcode.app on the unix server, and it will work. But in the production scenarios this is not a viable solution. I want to have a solution that works without refering the Xcode.app. Can someone help.

Comment: The symbolication tool uses items from the `iOS` SDK as part of it's workflow, so without some/all of `Xcode` on the server it's not going to work.

Comment: Petesh, Do u know the list of tools(from Xcode.app) that needs to go on to the server, in spite of putting the entire Xcode on the server which is more than 6Gigs and is not advisable.

Comment: Is your server running MacOS?

Comment: No. My server is a unix box.Its not running MacOS. I have the device crashes hitting the server, where I need to do the de-symbolication first before doing any further processing on the crash logs.